# Manipulating enclosing environment of a function

Tags: r, scope, closures, rlang

I'm trying to get a better understanding of [closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures), in particular details on a function's *scope* and how to work with its *enclosing environment(s)*

Based on the `Description` section of the help page on `rlang::fn_env()`, I had the understanding, that a function always has access to all variables in its scope and that its enclosing environment belongs to that scope.

But then, why isn't it possible to manipulate the contents of the closure environment "after the fact", i.e. after the function has been created?

By means of R's lexical scoping, shouldn't `bar()` be able to find `x` when I put into its enclosing environment?

```
foo <- function(fun) {
  env_closure <- rlang::fn_env(fun)
  env_closure$x <- 5
  fun()
}

bar <- function(x) x

foo(bar)
#> Error in fun(): argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I got it down now.

It has to do with the structure of a function's formal arguments:

If an argument is defined without a default value, R will complain when you call the function without specifiying that even though it might technically be able to look it up in its scope.

One way to kick off lexical scoping even though you don't want to define a default value would be to set the defaults "on the fly" at run time via `rlang::fn_fmls()`.

```
foo <- function(fun) {
  env_enclosing <- rlang::fn_env(fun)
  env_enclosing$x <- 5
  fun()
}

# No argument at all -> lexical scoping takes over
baz <- function() x
foo(baz)
#> [1] 5

# Set defaults to desired values on the fly at run time of `foo()`
foo <- function(fun) {
  env_enclosing <- rlang::fn_env(fun)
  env_enclosing$x <- 5
  fmls <- rlang::fn_fmls(fun)
  fmls$x <- substitute(get("x", envir = env_enclosing, inherits = FALSE))
  rlang::fn_fmls(fun) <- fmls
  fun()
}

bar <- function(x) x
foo(bar)
#> [1] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really follow your example as I am unfamiliar with the `rlang` library but I think a good example of a closure in R would be:

```
bucket <- function() {
    n <- 1
    foo <- function(x) {
        assign("n", n+1, envir = parent.env(environment()))
        n
    }
    foo
}
bar <- bucket()
```

Because `bar()` is define in the function environment of `bucket` then its parent environment is `bucket` and therefore you can carry some data there. Each time you run it you modify the `bucket` environment:

```
bar()
[1] 2
bar()
[1] 3
bar()
[1] 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm familiar with a "function created inside a function" approach, but was specifically trying to better understand enclosing environments for "function is created inside a non-functional environment" (e.g. namespace of a package or `.GlobalEnv`

Comment: Can you actually help me understand why you have access to `x` in your first example? It looks like `baz()` should have the parent environment `.GlobalEnv` and therefore look inside itself for `x` and then up to `.GlobalEnv` when it is evaluated inside `foo()`

Comment: OK, I get it: running the `rlang::fn_env()` modifies the environment of the function so its new parent becomes `foo()`... cool. So you're actually building a closure the same as my example but defining `baz()` separately and then modifying it.

Comment: Exactly :-) Don't know if I'll ever need that, but computing on the language itself is great fun. You should definitely check out the `rlang` package, yet another master piece by RStudio and friends :-)